# How do I hide a horizontal scrollbar on my Fancybox inline dialogue box on a Wordpress site?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fancybox, contact-form-7

I am trying to get rid of the scroll bar or the space that seems to be coded in somewhere (thinking maybe a Javascript file for the Fancybox plugin?) for my dialogue box. I've tried resizing the dialogue box and the from/content inside the box, but no matter the width of the content, it adds a blank space and a horizontal scroll bar. It's still usable, it just looks unprofessional and I want to fix it.

The dialogue box: click "REQUEST A SAMPLE KIT" @
http://colordynetech.com/markets/label-converters/

```
div#contact_form_pop{
font-weight:bold;
width:750px;
height:575px;
padding:30px;
}
div#sampletext{
font-weight:normal;
}
div#smaplekitform{
width:85%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove the horizontal scrollbar problem you have.

```
#fancybox-content > div {
  overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
```